# bm cause bold font undefined problems

Tags: fonts, bold, unicode-math, bm

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}
\usepackage{bm}
\renewcommand{\bm}{\symbf}


\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

\end{document}
```

This causes the warning

```
Font shape `TU/Asana-Math.otf(1)/b/n' undefined
(Font)  using `TU/Asana-Math.otf(1)/m/n' instead.
```

But if I deleted the lines

```
\usepackage{bm}
\renewcommand{\bm}{\symbf}
```

the warnings disappeared.

Why? How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

As the message says the font you are using does not have a bold font. `\symbf` does not change fonts it selects the bold math alphabet range from the same font. More generally `bm` is mostly incompatible with `unicode-math` (I did look to extending it but there are some technical issues).

There is of course no point in the the first line here

```
\usepackage{bm}
\renewcommand{\bm}{\symbf}
```

As the renewcommand undoes the definition of the package, just use

```
\newcommand\bm{\symbf}`
```

If you want to alias `\symbf` to `\bm` perhaps because you are coverting an existing pdftex document using `bm` package to `unicode-math`, otherwise don't use `\bm` at all and use `\symbf` in your math formulae.

Note the question asks about aliasing `\bm` to `\symbf` so that's what I show above, but for letters, such as x,  `\bm{x}` is bold math italic not bold upright so `\symbfit` might be a better choice.

Comment: Should `bm` perhaps bail out if `unicode-math` is loaded?

Comment: @JosephWright well if there is a bold font I can make it work (partly I gave up at the time as the luatex interface to \Umathchar was somwhat unstable at the time), but mostly there isn't a bold font (but then possibly  It should use the FakeBold font feature to make a bold font). It's on the list of things to look at......

Comment: `Command \bm already defined.` it says this and do not output a PDF. I use `xelatex`

Comment: @1900011604 `\bm` will not already be defined if you do not define it twice. Did you remove the `\usepackage{bm}` as I suggested?

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to remove the `\usepackage{bm}`

Comment: @David Carlisle \symbf{x} gives me a roman bold x, whereas \bm{x} gave me an italic bold x. Shouldn’t I use \mathbfit{x} instead ?

Comment: Or maybe \symbfit is better?

Comment: @Didier yes it looks like I answered the question as asked which is  why the warning goes if you define bm to be symbf but should have commented that  symbfit would be better

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you very much. symbfit works fine

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to not use `\bm` and directly replace it from `\mathbf`

```
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\usepackage[scr=rsfso,frak=euler,bb=ams]{mathalpha}
\usepackage[bold-style=ISO,sans-style=italic]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \let\uglymathbf\mathbf
  \renewcommand\mathbf\symbf
  \let\uglymathsf\mathsf
  \renewcommand\mathsf\symsf
}
```