# \bm and Lualatex

Tags: luatex, bm

I just moved from PDFLatex to Lualatex. So, I am a real beginner with Lualatex and I am probably doing something wrong.
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[math-style=french]{unicode-math}
\usepackage[scale={0.75,0.8},footskip=1.5cm,heightrounded]{geometry}


\begin{document}
    $\alpha+\Gamma=a+X$
    
    $\bm{x}$
\end{document}
```

And here is the result:
[image]

As you can see, the x from the second line is not there.
I have no doubt that the error is coming from me because the package bm works fine.
I checked in the log file and it seems to be a font problem:

Missing character: There is no  (U+1D465) in font cmbx10!
[1

So I guess, I have to change the font.
Can anyone tell me how to change the font so that bm works fine. I guess there are many fonts but I am looking for a font like Times new roman (I find the font in my MWE too thin).
I guess I will encounter other problems with Lualatex, won't I?

PS: Sorry for my poor English (I am French)
PS: I did some research before posting and I found this topic: [Lualatex and bm package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314863/lualatex-and-bm-package). But that didn't help me

Comment: Since you load the `unicode-math` package, you can use `\mathbfit{x}` instead of `\bm{x}` and remove the `bm` package. This should work. Maybe have a look at the [`unicode-math` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.pdf).

Comment: bm doesn't work with unicode-math see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/643204/2388

Comment: Thank you for your answers. \mathbfit seems to work fine